# angularjs Set image while waiting for controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an angularjs-Application.

In one Controller i´m waiting for an image source address - I get this from an PHP-Service.

```
controller.controller("LayoutCtrl", 
["$scope", "$http", "$route", 
function($scope, $http, $route) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
    $http.get('zkLib/services/header.php').success(function(data) { 
        $scope.header = data; });
}]);
```

The header.php looks like this:

```
$result = array();

$result['index'] = db()->loadSetting('index_page');
$result['banner'] = db()->loadSetting('site_banner');

echo json_encode($result);
```

So in my template i´ve written:

```
        <div ng-controller="LayoutCtrl">
            <div desc="header">
                <a desc='hp_link' href="#{{header.index}}">
                    <img desc='banner' ng-src="zkLib/f/img/{{header.banner}}">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Problem is now:

When the site opens, it shows the "NoImage"-Icon from the Browser while waiting for this service.
After this the image will be viewed correctly.

But in my COnsole i have this error too:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:160/cms/app/zkLib/f/img/".
```

On my Server i have the image 'loading.gif', i want to show this while i´m waiting for my service.

How to solve this? Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error in the console is because, before the request to header.php completes and angular renders {{header.banner}}, its trying to load just "zkLib/f/img/". You can fix this by putting the entire relative url into the {{header.banner}} scope property.For example...

```
<img desc='banner' ng-src="{{header.banner}}">
```

and make header.banner be the full relative path...

```
$http.get('zkLib/services/header.php').success(function(data) { 
    $scope.header = data;
    $scope.bannerImage = 'zkLib/f/img/' + $scope.header.banner;
});
```

Now, before the request is complete, the image src will be an empty string and it won't show the broken image icon or throw the error. If you want to show a loading image before the controller loads, you can just set src, like this...

```
<img desc='banner' ng-src="{{bannerImage}}" src="/path/to/loading.gif">
```

Before the request is complete, the src will be the loading.gif file. Once the request completes, ng-src will kick in and your header.banner image will be displayed

Comment: Thanks - with booth its working.

img-Tag:
`<img desc='banner' ng-src="{{header.banner}}" src="zkLib/f/img/ajax-loader-sm.gif">`
Then return the full url to the picture and it works with the animation :)

Answer (score 1):

When the controller is instantiated, `$scope.header` is still empty.

This makes `ng-src="zkLib/f/img/{{header.banner}}"` to be evaluated to this relative path:

```
'zkLib/f/img/' // translates to "http://localhost:160/cms/app/zkLib/f/img/"
```

---

What you need to do is to keep `ng-src` empty while `$scope.header` is empty.

#### #1) One way is to write this:

```
<img desc='banner' ng-if="header" ng-src="zkLib/f/img/{{header.banner}}">
```

#### #2) Or this (if you don't want to use `ngIf`):

```
<img desc='banner' ng-src="{{ header && 'zkLib/f/img/' + header.banner }}">
```

#### #3) But I would prefer to create the link inside the controller:

```
$http.get('zkLib/services/header.php').success(function(data) { 
  $scope.header = data;
  $scope.banner = 'zkLib/f/img/' + data.banner;
});
```

And then just use it easily:

```
<img desc='banner' ng-src="{{ banner }}">
```